# How do I display symbols in the editor instead of text?

Tags: symbols, editors

Whenever I click a symbol to insert into the editor it just inserts a description of the symbol, instead of the actual symbol image that's displayed on the left in the symbols panel.

If we wish to use LaTeX as simply a comprehensive MathType tool and not to compile code, how may this be done?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). I think you are misunderstanding the point of `LaTeX`. For a few things you can use unicode symbols (and that depends on the particular editor), but `LaTeX` is not intended to be a WYSIWYG editor in general. I don't use unicode so some else can better explain that.

Comment: It depends on the editor you use. It is possible that the exact command that is inserted when you select a particular symbol is configurable somewhere. If this is the case, you can change that configuration to insert the appropiate unicode symbol. Note that this could break your TeX compilation unless you use the appropiate packages to accept unicode in math.

Comment: I see. @Peter Grill Would you have any recommendations for an editor that I could use to write formal mathematical proofs using inline mathematical symbols?

Comment: I personally would recommend `TeXShop` if you are on a Mac, but `TeXWorks` otherwise. See [What are the advantages of TeXShop over TeXworks?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34518/what-are-the-advantages-of-texshop-over-texworks).  But, for a more general information on selecting an editor see [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides).

Comment: As it stands, this is either unclear or a dupe. I've gone for the first one, but Peter's advice also stands.